# How to access greatgrandchild elements from Elementtree in python?

Tags: python, elementtree

I having difficulty in accessing the great-grandchildren using element tree in python.
Specifically, I want access the tree of Ev,Ec,St,DU and Si. The full xml is attached together at the bottom of this thread.

I tried the following code, but it return nothing.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('shhs_eval.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for ScoreEvent in root.findall('Sco'):
    Event = ScoreEvent.find('Ev').text
    Start = ScoreEvent.find('St').text
    print(Event,Start)
```

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <PSG>
    <Sof>Compumedics</Sof>
    <Ep>30</Ep>
    <Scs>
    <Sco>
        <Ev>Arousal</Ev>
        <Ec>Arousal|Arousal ()</Ec>
        <St>8062.4</St>
        <Du>22.8</Du>
        <Si>EMG</Si>
    </Sco>
    <Sco>
        <Ev>N1</Ev>
        <Evc>wl|Aw ()</Evc>
        <St>8062.4</St>
        <Du>22.8</Du>
        <Si>EMG</Si>
    </Sco>
    </Scs>
    </PSG>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far and if there's any error, include that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `<Sco>` is not a direct child of the root, you have to access it with using `findall(.//<node>)` (depth first search).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sshs_eval.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for ScoreEvent in root.findall('.//Sco'):
    Event = ScoreEvent.find('Ev').text
    Start = ScoreEvent.find('St').text
    print(Event,Start)
```

Comment: May I know why we have  .// . Is it represent search? Anyhow, thanks for the solution, really appreciate it

Comment: It's depth first search. It looks for all instances of nested <node>. Would you mind selecting this as the answer if it's correct? :)

Comment: Yes, I already accepted you post as an answer for this posting. Thanks